# generic javascript udf for json deserialization in bigquery

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I was planning to create a bigquery javascript udf to parse json (as json functions are still in preview phase). Now, if I write a function, then a return type has to be specified.
For example:
If my json function has to return an array of records, then the return type looks like the following in function declaration:

```
    create temp function de_serialize_json(json_string string)
returns array<struct<id string, points float64, description string, long_description string>>
language js as r"""
  return JSON.parse(json_string)
"""
;
```

Is there a way to generalize the return data structure? Meaning, I can input json of any structure and the output can be obtained w/o changing the return structure.

Please let me know.

Comment: Can't you use [JSON functionality](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data) of BigQuery?

Comment: I dont have access to preview functions of BigQuery. Hence, asked. I did already go through those details. Why would I go through so much pains if I had access.

Comment: btw, not sure if coming new JSON stuff will address your question! not sure at all!

Comment: @AishwaryShukla what you are doing with UDF is convert JSON string to STRUCT which requires a fixed structure. Hence there is no other way than specifying return type.

Comment: @AishwaryShukla, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can try the feature by filling the [enrollment form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSddXvPWHVsKBC2LMNab2eDbEa8Bw9DhTmsto4-7FrUCwePpNw/viewform). Right now, the way you are trying to achieve this is the  way available since BigQuery has a fixed structure to convert JSON to struct. If you want to use the [JSON](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data#overview) data then you have to wait until it is available in GA since there is no generic return data structure available.